# 404 not found java config spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

В общем делаю я тут небольшой проект на `spring MVC`. Конфигурация решил делать на чистой `java` вобще без `xml`. Проблема в том, что вроде как все инициализировал верно, однако контейнер по какой-то причине не запускается и вылетает 404. Приведу часть кода:

`webconfig.java`

```
    import com.myapp.webapp.Interceptors.AccountInterceptor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.myapp.service",
"com.myapp.webapp"
} )
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/jsp/**").addResourceLocations("/jsp/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    AccountInterceptor accountInterceptor() {
        return new AccountInterceptor();
    }


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(accountInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/account/**");
    }


}
```

`webservletconfiguration.java`

```
    import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;


public class WebServletConfiguration extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
            WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebConfig.class
        };
    }
```

Ну и например контроллер(Самый простой)

```
    import com.myapp.model.Account;
import com.myapp.model.Phone;
import com.myapp.service.Service;
import com.myapp.webapp.utils.SetAttributes;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



@Controller
@SessionAttributes("accountInSession")
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    Service<Account> accountService;


    @RequestMapping("/join")
    public ModelAndView join(){
        return new ModelAndView("join");
    }

 //тут дальше много всяких методов, не стал их добавлять, так как в данном 
 //случае они не играют никакой роли
}
```

если я правильно понимаю, то в том случае, когда я захожу на `http://localhost:8085/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/account/join` он меня должен перекинуть на `join.jsp`, который хранится в `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

`главный pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>socialnet</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compile.version>3.3</maven.compile.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.194</h2.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.17</mysql.version>
        <dbcp.version>2.1</dbcp.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <maven.deploy.version>2.8.2</maven.deploy.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <tomcat.servler.version>9.0.0.M4</tomcat.servler.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jquery.version>2.1.4</jquery.version>
    </properties>


    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>dao</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>webapp</module>
    </modules>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compile.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.deploy.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`pom.xml в webapp`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>socialnet</artifactId>
        <groupId>myapp</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.servler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Вы делаете это на Spring boot ? Tomcat ?

Comment: spring boot не использую. Да, приложение деплою на томкат

Comment: Вам 404 ошибку дает сам томткат  ? [Примерно вот это видите ?](https://kb.globalscape.com/attachments/ME/TomcatError.PNG) Покажите свой web.xml пожалуйста.

Comment: как я написал выше я использую java config. У меня нет в проекте web.xml

Comment: `*.pom` покажите! Плагин подключили чтобы деплоить без `web.xml`?

Comment: добавил, да подключал

Comment: А разве инициализация Spring конфига не нужна? Где оно?

Comment: При использовании `xml` конфигурации мы в `web.xml`  инициализируем единственный сервлет(`dispatcher servlet`). В данном случае он инициализируется в `webServletConfiguration.java`. Дальше в случае `xml` конфигурации мы должна задать контекст для этого сервлета, в данном случае его конфигурация по идее должна задаваться в файле `webConfig.java`. Так что по идее все должно работать, ну или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: Поидее да, но, насколько я знаю, для приложения Tomcat нужна "точка входа" и эта точка входа есть web.xml. Можете выложить код на гитхаб? Попробую отдебажить